# Cannot find name 'BrowserAnimationsModules' in Angular CLI 8, PrimeNG

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG theme and it's component table . When I follow their instructions https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup about usage to install and to install npm install primeng --save, npm install primeicons --save and npm install @angular/animations --save I have problem with the third one. In app.module.ts I added as import import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; and then in

```
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule
        //...
    ],
    //...
})
```

But I'm receiving the error Cannot find name 'BrowserAnimationsModules'.
I uninstalled npm packages then, reinstalled but this hasn't changed anything. 
My package.json file is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^8.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  }
```

I googled a lot, but hasn't found an answer. Can somebody help?

Comment: Can you add a stackblitz with the example. It might be environment specific and if you can't reproduce we won't be able to help you much.

Comment: @Ivana BrowserAnimationsModule should be loaded only in AppModule (or the root module), make sure they're not included in SharedModule or any other sub-modules. If you have added it anywhere else please remove the same

Answer (score -1):

`BrowserAnimationsModule` should be loaded only in `AppModule` (either in your root module or a core module), make sure they're not included in `SharedModule` or any other `sub-modules`. If you have added it anywhere else please remove the same.

Also, note that the `BrowserAnimationsModule` contains the `BrowserModule` so no need to import it. you can remove the `BrowserModule` from the imports

Comment: also, make sure you stop the `ng serve` and  run it again sometimes there is a cache issue